# Can SpEL be passed an enviroment variable directly or is a properties file in some form always required?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-el

We build micro services and I am working on a generic way of generating documentation for them. This has created a situation where I need to set a variable which is static across all our services yet has two possible values depending on the environment the service is deployed in. Hence I would like to inject a value based directly on an environment variable rather than through my Application.yml file, and it's various profiles, as I would usually do. Is there any way to do this?

Here is an example of what I imagine this would look like (with a syntax similar to what it would have looked like if it was a regular property in Application.yml):

```
@Value("#{enviromentProperties['environment'].equals['production'] ? jupiter : mars}")
private String APIGatewayHostname;
```

Just to be clear we have situations where we deploy several profiles behind the same proxy. Hence we want the hostname reference to be the proxy host so people don't attempt to call the service directly as this is not possible. We only have one proxy per environment regardless which profiles we are running at any given time hence my desire to use an environment variable rather than a property. Also this proxy is not really a part of the design of the services themselves so it seems counter intuitive to store it in multiple profiles in the Application.yml file.

NB: If there are other better ways to accomplish this feel free to let me know :)

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, you should look into [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for specifying an "environment", e.g. 'production' vs 'development' vs 'test'.

Comment: I'm using profiles already. The problem is that since this setting remains the same for several different applications adding the property in each corresponding Application.yml greatly increases the risk of human error. Also I don't love the idea that the default profile sets the variable to correspond to the hostname for test, but unless I include this there I would need to specify the property for every test profile adding even more possibilities for human error.